# MANTT First Class when was this first done

Tags: mantt

I am trying to find out when a patent for MANTT First Class from company LASP was first filed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to

> Kit for a telescopic roof with a snow melting device translated from German
>   [DE 60201004](http://www.google.com/patents/DE60201004T2?cl=en)

It has an October 11 2001 priority date. You can search in google patents advanced and enter LASP as the applicant to dig deeper yourself.